# Creating a zip archive in C++

Tags: c++, compression, zip

Is there a simple way to create a zip archive in C++? I'm writing a GPL app and I looked in to minizip but it seems too complicated. Is there a simple library to do this? I already have the files on the disk, I just want to make a zip from them.

Comment: Yeah.. It's licensed GPL.. If I'm using a library, I don't want licensing conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use zlib as a compression library in your C++ app (zlib.net). I've used it before and I believe it's the best option. If you look around you may also find some C++ wrappers that simplify the code.

Comment: I can't find a tutorial for it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [7-zip library](http://www.7-zip.org/), it's LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

E.g. [Infozip](http://www.info-zip.org/)

Answer (score 0):

It is C, but possibly still a good option: http://libarchive.github.com/